# Mailgun account disabled soon after signing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailgun

I was trying to test/explore mailgun for email service. Soon after signing up I am getting the following text

[image]

Then I thought that it could be because I haven't verified any domain. But, when I try to add a domain I am getting the following msg:

[image]

And when I tried to send email, using `gem 'mailgun-ruby', '~>1.1.2'` and `mailgun sandboxdomain`, from ruby `console` I have the following errors displayed

[image]

Seems like `account disabled` is the issue here. I had just signedup and my account is disabled. Any help on this?

Comment: do you contact support?

Comment: Yeah, I have sent an email. Not sure how time will it take? I even tried creating second account and soon after signing up, same issue `Account disabled`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you've stumbled across some of the automated checks that mailgun uses to filter out spam accounts.  It doesn't mean your intent or use is spam, it could be because the IP address was flagged in the past.

This is their webpage that explains what's happened and what information they'll need from you to reactivate your account.

https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/202850080-What-does-business-verification-is-required-mean-

Comment: Would this happen even if I was using mailgun for the first time?

Comment: Yes, as the website states it could be because of how your IP address was used previously or could be any number of issues that aren't your fault. Follow the instructions on the link I provided (it explains exactly what information they need) and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you. I have a small task/challenge to integrate mailgun into rails app. Hope the support people respond soon. Before the task expires i.e. by tonight.

Comment: Ah, well, good luck! I would advise your customer / employer that there may possibly be a delay.